How to refresh a subgrid on a modal popup unload in Power Pages
I have a basic page (Entity form) which contains a subgrid (added as a metadata record) with an Add button to add new records. On clicking the Add button, a modal form pops up.
Currently when we use the modal popup to create a new record and then close it the subgrid on the calling page doesn't refresh to show the new record.
How can I get the subgrid to refresh?
